# How to access the raw unaltered http POST data in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I access the original `POST` message in a controller and *send it back unaltered* to its original sender?

Comment: What do you mean "send back"? To the browser?

Comment: I'm using Rails as an API. In this case, I'm sending back to the server that made the original POST for verification purposes.

Comment: Hello there! @joscas, Could you please include in this question, the code to actually SEND the request back to its sender?
it'd seem that request.raw_post only gives you the thing you intend to send back, right?

Comment: Found very few questions talking about this and thank god, I got it working now.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use [`ActionDispatch::Request#raw_post`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-raw_post) to get the unaltered POST data:

```rb
request.raw_post
```

Comment: Hi Philip, I looked into that link, and request.raw_post appears to be used to fetch the request content, but How do you actually send the request back to the sender? can you help me?

Comment: @JoseE -- `render :text => request.raw_post`. You may have to specify some headers for MIME type. If you know you're always working with a specific format (xml or json), it's better to supply that than `:text`, as in `render :json => request.raw_post`.