# Upload CSV via POST in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I am trying to upload a csv file to Rails and parse it into a db. I have tried using both Paw and Postman to send the http request, specifying POST, attaching the csv file, and specifying Content-Type as application/csv

The request header:

```
POST /skate_parks/import HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/csv
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.3.4 (Macintosh; OS X/10.11.5) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 11663

Name,Address,Suburb,Postcode,State,Business Category,LGA,Region,
Aireys Inlet Skate Park,Great Ocean Road,Aireys Inlet,3231,VIC,Skate Parks,Surf Coast,Barwon S/W, etc...
```

The controller skate_parks_controller.rb

```
def import
  SkatePark.import(params[:body])
end
```

The model

```
class SkatePark < ApplicationRecord

  require 'csv'

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach("file", headers: true) do |row|

      skate_park_hash = row.to_hash
      skate_park = SkatePark.where(name: skate_park_hash["name"])

      if skate_park.count == 1
        skate_park.first.update_attributes(skate_park_hash)
      else
        SkatePark.create!(skate_park_hash)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The error

```
Started POST "/skate_parks/import" for ::1 at 2016-05-26 13:48:34 +1000
Processing by SkateParksController#import as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - file):
app/models/skate_park.rb:6:in `import'
app/controllers/skate_parks_controller.rb:7:in `import'
```

Comment: Uploading a csv is the same as any other file type. With that in mind it might be easier to find your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `params[:body]` is `nil`, so you're essentially calling `SkatePark.import(nil)`. Rails doesn't put the raw POST body into `params` like you've apparently assumed it does.

You have two options. The better option, in my opinion, is to upload the data as `multipart/form-data`. Rather than putting the raw data into the POST body, you'll do the same thing a browser does when a user chooses a file in an `<input type="file">`, which is to say you'll encode it as form data. When you do that, you *will* be able to access the data through `params`, as described in the [Form Helpers Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files) under "Uploading Files." (Since you apparently aren't using a form, you can skip to "What Gets Uploaded" to see how to handle the data you receive.)

To test this with Postman, follow the instructions for "form-data" under "Request body" in the [Sending Requests](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests) docs, which I'll excerpt here for posterity:

> multipart/form-data is the default encoding a web form uses to transfer data. This simulates filling a form on a website, and submitting it. The form-data editor lets you set key/value pairs (using the [key-value editor](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/keyvalue_editor)) for your data. You can attach files to a key as well.

Your other option is to access the POST body directly via `request.raw_post` as described here: [How to access the raw unaltered http POST data in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306310/how-to-access-the-raw-unaltered-http-post-data-in-rails) This is not very "Railsy," however, and among other things will be harder to test.